# Given an array of integers find sum of integers which would be in sorted array between given positions

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to find the best possible algorithm(complexity) for my task.

Input: indexes first, last and array

Output: sum of integers in the same array after being sorted between positions first and last.

Numbers in array are different(can be negative)!

For example: 
Input: first = 3, last = 7, array = {5,4,2,6,8,9,0,-1,3}

Output: 26(3+4+5+6+8)

What I've tried =>

1. We can easily sort array and just calculate it, it will be O(nlogn)
2. We can count differences between number of elements in array and
   our indexes first and last and choose counted number of maximum elements or minimum and remove from our actual sum of the array.

For example: count sum of (n-last) maximum integers and then count sum of (first - 0) minimum integers and subtract from our actual sum, however it will not always be good idea, because finding this number of maximum or minimum integers in array can be expensive. Of course I can easily make some improvements such as calculate when it is better to take sum of (n-last) maximum numbers or only (last) maximum numbers.

What am I asking for is whether there is better solution to this problem then solving some equations and making huge amount of if's to improve it.

Comment: Why not a single pass? Just check if the element is between your bounds.

Comment: But I have indexes, not numbers in array

Comment: I see what your saying now. Your example threw me off a little with the first one being `3`.

Comment: Since you are dealing with integers, you could essentially create your own type of `ordered set`. I think this would be more efficient.

Comment: @JosephWood : Why do you think that would be more efficient.  I can't see how to create an ordered set in less than O(n log n).

Comment: @MartinBonner: It depends on whether the range of values is restricted.  If it is, you can build a histogram in linear time, and then evaluate the histogram in O(M) time, linear in the range of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `std::nth_element` algorithm, which separates "first N" from "elements past N" without doing the extra work of sorting inside the two partitions.

For your purposes, you'll need to call `nth_element` twice.  The second call will be on one of the partitions created in the first step, not the whole array.  At the end, you'll have three partitions:

- Elements less than those you need
- Elements you need
- Elements greater than those you need

and it typically does this in linear time, although worst-case is still O(N lg N)

Comment: This is an awesome approach. The benchmarks back it up as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that is faster than the proposed solution by the OP. Though not as elegant or general as the excellent solution provided by @BenVoigt, it is almost as fast.

```
double boundedSumJoe(std::vector<int> x, int lower, int upper) {

    int myMax = *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end());
    int offSet = std::abs(*std::min_element(x.begin(), x.end())) + 1;
    unsigned long int myRange;

    if (myMax > 0)
        myRange = myMax + offSet;  // E.g. if myMax = 10 & myMin = -2, then myRange = 12
    else
        myRange = offSet;

    offSet--;

    std::vector<int> frequency(myRange, 0);
    std::vector<int> values(myRange, 0);
    std::vector<int>::iterator it, itEnd = x.end();
    int myIndex;
    double mySum = 0;

    for (it = x.begin(); it < itEnd; it++) {
        myIndex = *it + offSet;
        frequency[myIndex]++;
        values[myIndex] = *it;
    }

    int count = 0;
    bool firstHit = true;

    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < myRange; j++) {
        if (frequency[j]) {
            if (count >= lower) {
                if (count <= upper) {
                    firstHit = false;
                    mySum += values[j] * frequency[j];
                } else {
                    if ((count - upper) > 1) {
                        int k = j - 1;
                        while (!frequency[k]) {k--;}
                        mySum -= (values[k] * (count - upper - 1));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            count += frequency[j];
            if ((count - lower) >= 1 && firstHit) {
                firstHit = false;
                mySum += (values[j] * (count - lower));
            }
        }
    }

    return mySum;
}
```

We first create two vectors large enough to span the entire range of input values. One of them keeps the values from the input vector and the other keeps a tally of that value (frequency vector above). Elements are added in order as the index is made from the value itself.

We then loop over the frequency vector and sum up the resulting values between our two bounds. <s>A shortcoming of the above method is that it generally will return incorrect results if there are duplicate values in the input vector.</s> Thanks to the suggestions by @BenVoigt, the above can now handle input vectors with duplicate values. As you can see, some care is needed on the edges (hence the additional `if ((count - upper) > 1)` as well as the lines following `if ((count - lower) >= 1 && firstHit)`).

Here are some very basic benchmarks that truly show the power of the solution provided by @BenVoigt. First off, here is an implementation of the OP and an implementation using `std::nth_element`.

```
double boundedSumOP(std::vector<int> x, int lower, int upper) {
    double mySum = 0;
    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
    std::vector<int>::iterator it, itEnd = x.begin() + upper;
    for (it = x.begin() + lower; it <= itEnd; it++)
        mySum += *it;
    return mySum;
}

double boundedSumBen(std::vector<int> x, int lower, int upper) {
    double mySum = 0;
    // First partition vector at larger bound
    std::nth_element(x.begin(), x.begin() + upper, x.end());
    // Now create partition of above at lower bound
    std::nth_element(x.begin(), x.begin() + lower, x.begin() + upper);
    std::vector<int>::iterator it, itEnd = x.begin() + upper;
    for (it = x.begin() + lower; it <= itEnd; it++)
        mySum += *it;
    return mySum;
}
```

Here is the main function that is used for testing, somewhat crude I might add:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(200001);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), -100000);
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);

    // random-sample without replacement
    std::vector<int> randVec(v.begin(), v.begin() + 100000);
    int val1, val2, val3;
    std::clock_t start_time, end_time;

    start_time = clock();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val1 = boundedSumBen(randVec, 49900, 50100);
    end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "time taken on sample w/o rep std::nth_element : " <<
        end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    start_time = clock();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val2 = boundedSumJoe(randVec, 49900, 50100);
    end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "time taken on sample w/o rep indexing method by Joe : " <<
        end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    start_time = clock();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val3 = boundedSumOP(randVec, 49900, 50100);
    end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "time taken on sample w/o rep naive approach with std::sort : " <<
        end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    std::cout << "All functions on sample w/o rep return the same value of : " <<
        val1 << ", " << val2 << ", and " << val3 << std::endl;


    // Now we test a random sample with replacement
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(-100000, 100000);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        randVec[i] = distribution(gen);

    start_time = clock();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val1 = boundedSumBen(randVec, 9900, 10100);
    end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "time taken on sample with rep std::nth_element : " <<
        end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    start_time = clock();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val2 = boundedSumJoe(randVec, 9900, 10100);
    end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "time taken on sample with rep indexing method by Joe : " <<
        end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    start_time = clock();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val3 = boundedSumOP(randVec, 9900, 10100);
    end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "time taken on sample with rep naive approach with std::sort : " <<
        end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    std::cout << "All functions on sample with rep return the same value of : " <<
        val1 << ", " << val2 << ", and " << val3 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Number of unique elements in vector with replacement "
             << std::set<int>(randVec.begin(), randVec.end()).size()
             << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the results on my computer* (I'm using `clang++`) :

```
time taken on sample w/o rep std::nth_element : 109925
time taken on sample w/o rep indexing method by Joe : 110162
time taken on sample w/o rep naive approach with std::sort : 581368
All functions on sample w/o rep return the same value of : 38849, 38849, and 38849

time taken on sample with rep std::nth_element : 93542
time taken on sample with rep indexing method by Joe : 102780
time taken on sample with rep naive approach with std::sort : 517273
All functions on sample with rep return the same value of : -16069147, -16069147, and -16069147

Number of unique elements in vector with replacement 78605
```

As you can see, employing the `std::nth_element` provided by @BenVoigt is superior in terms of both speed and generality, while the indexing method is still quite a bit faster than the naive approach.

- Here are the results from [ideone](https://ideone.com/rl53Ly) (running `gcc`).

Comment: Note that the bitmask method can't handle repeated entries.  Building a histogram that can represent repeats is not difficult (replace `myBools[myIndex] = 1;` with `myBools[myIndex]++;` and probably rename the variable to be more accurate) but the summation code becomes more complicated.

Comment: Also your use of `nth_element` appears to be wrong.  It certainly differs from what I answered, that "The second call will be on one of the partitions created in the first step, not the whole array."  Since you got the correct result, I'm suspicious that your test case might not be a valid test.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks for your suggestion of building a histogram. I will definitely keep that in mind.  Also, sorry for mucking up the `nth_element` call.  I have corrected it.  Interestingly enough, before I corrected it an ran it on ideone, I was not getting the same values as the other two methods, but when I ran it on my own machine, it was working fine. I'm guessing the difference in compilers has something to do with it.  Anywho, I really appreciate your comments and all of your great answers.  I have learned so much reading your post on c++.